# Conversion constructor from base class pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a question related to homework. Basically I have to realize a scientific calculator.

Suppose that simplified code / hierarchy which represents a literal :

```
struct Literal {
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};
struct NumericLiteral : public Literal {};
struct IntegerLiteral : public NumericLiteral {
    int value;
    IntegerLiteral(int value) : value(value) {}
    std::string toString() const override { return std::to_string(value); }
};
struct RationalLiteral : public NumericLiteral {
    int num, den;
    RationalLiteral(int den, int num) : num(num), den(den) {}
    RationalLiteral(IntegerLiteral il) : num(il.value), den(1) {}
    std::string toString() const override { return std::to_string(num) + '/' + std::to_string(den); }
};
struct RealLiteral : public NumericLiteral {
    double value;
    RealLiteral(double value) : value(value) {}
    RealLiteral(IntegerLiteral il) : value(il.value) {}
    RealLiteral(RationalLiteral rl) : value(rl.num / (double)rl.den) {}
    std::string toString() const override { return std::to_string(value); }
};
struct ExpressionLiteral : public Literal {
    std::string expr;
    ExpressionLiteral() {}
    ExpressionLiteral(std::string expr) : expr(expr) {}
    ExpressionLiteral(IntegerLiteral nl) : expr(nl.toString()) {}
    ExpressionLiteral(RationalLiteral rl) : expr(rl.toString()) {}
    ExpressionLiteral(RealLiteral rl) : expr(rl.toString()) {}
    std::string toString() const override { return expr; }
};
```

As you can see, there is conversion constructor from the less general literals to the more general literals, *e.g.* Integer to Real.

At some point, I'll have to apply an operator of arity **n** on operands of type `Literal *`, and I need to get a vector of **concrete** literals based on the more general (`ExpressionLiteral > RealLiteral [...] > IntegerLiteral`).

So I tried something like this (example for `ExpressionLiteral`)  :

```
std::vector<ExpressionLiteral> v;
for (auto op : args) v.push_back(ExpressionLiteral(*op));
```

where `args` is `std::vector<Literal*>`.

This was unsuccessful as `ExpressionLiteral` has no conversion constructor for `Literal`.

How can I call the conversion constructor corresponding to the real type of the `Literal` pointed ?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Implement a `virtual clone` function?

Comment: What is the point of `ExpressionLiteral`? It looks like you just want `v.push_back(op->toString())`?

Comment: Try initialize parent constructor with your child constructor. Such as ExpressionLiteral () : Literal () {}

Comment: @Barry It is part of the subject as a Literal which can be parsed and evaluated later.

Comment: I suggest you look at how to use a "cast operator", http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

I would also recommend you use `auto & op`, otherwise you create a _copy_ of every ExpressionLiteral. I even further recommend you `v.reserve(args.size())`

Comment: @NathanOliver May you give a prototype example ?

Comment: @inetknght Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: @Chostakovitch It is just a virtual function that returns a copy of the actual type the pointer points to.  Since copy constructors cannot be virtual this is a way to get around that.  If every class has a clone function that returns a copy then your for loop would look like `for (auto op : args) v.push_back(op->clone());`

Comment: @NathanOliver But in that case, there is no conversion, right ? My goal would be to convert any Literal (i.e. Integer, Rational, Real, Expression) in more general Literal, so here `op` could be any of these and must convert to `ExpressionLiteral`

Answer (score 1):

You need a way for a `Literal` to convert itself to an `ExpressionLiteral`, where that conversion is dependent on the runtype type of the `Literal`. That's what `virtual` functions are for:

```
struct Literal {
    virtual ExpressionLiteral asExpression() const = 0;
};
```